# Trouble with JOptionPane variable from another class

Tags: java, joptionpane

I set up some simple code using JOptionPane to open a simple showMessageDialog when a button is clicked. Everything worked fine. Now I'm complicating things by retrieving a double variable from another class. I've tried a few different things, but I'm still getting a "not applicable for arguments" error. I've tried reading over the full Oracle documentation and watched a few YouTube videos, but I'm still struggling.

Three classes, one for the GUI, one for the event handling, and for retrieving the number from.

Here is the code excerpt:

```
public class TEST_GUI {

   private JButton testButton;

   public void GUI {
      //construction of the GUI occurs here
      testButton = new JButton("Tester");
   }



protected class EventHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent testButtonClicked) {        

        if (testButtonClicked.getSource() == testButton){
            TesterClass tester = new TesterClass();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,tester.getRetrievedNumber());
        }
    }
}



public class TesterClass {

    private double retrievedNumber;

    public TesterClass(){
        retrievedNumber = 1000.00;
    }

    public double getRetrievedNumber() {
        return this.retrievedNumber;
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine with the generic (null,"message") arguments, but it won't accept my double variable from the other class. I'd appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
tester.getRetrievedNumber()
```

with

```
String.valueOf(tester.getRetrievedNumber());
```

---

That said

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

Since we can see that [`showMessageDialog`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JOptionPane.java#JOptionPane.showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) takes an object as 2nd parameter, [**AutoBoxing**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) should work here and your `double` gets casted into a `Double` object.

In **Eclipse**, it works fine using a primitive as parameter.

Maybe the problem lays elsewhere but I can not find it. Maybe with more info...

Comment: Thank you!! So can only strings be passed to the JOptionPane window? Is that the whole problem? So simple, I'm surprised I missed that. Or is there more to it?

Comment: I'm investigating. It works for a double in Eclipse somehow. I'll edit my answer once I get the exact reason.

Comment: @bnr32jason, unable to find the problem since it works fine with me. Implicitely casting the primitive as an object may be a temporary solution like above with a String.